# How do I update a single subelement in an array by two references

Tags: mongodb, meteor, mongodb-query

I have a school document structure like this:

```
{
    "_id":"tnoMB2PhsPPQKcafz",
    // some other property here
    "students":[{
        "student":{
            "ref_id":"eaH7JsponapSWCGf6",
            "name":"name",
            "family":"family",
            "grade":12
        },
        // many other student here
]}
```

I want to update grade property for determined student in determined school but I don't know how to do this.

For example I have school _id (**tnoMB2PhsPPQKcafz**) and student ref_id (**eaH7JsponapSWCGf6**) and want to update determined student grade from 12 to 18.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `$elemMatch` as below :

```
db.school.update({"_id" : "tnoMB2PhsPPQKcafz","students":{"$elemMatch":{"student.ref_id":"eaH7JsponapSWCGf6"}}},{"$set":{"students.$.student.grade":18}})
```

Comment: Thanks man. This is work well. I'm going to read more about $elemMatch.